# SQL subquery in select that returns multiple records in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to have a select subquery return multiple records in a single column like this example?
[image: Example]

**example code:**

```
select u.fname,
       u.lname,
       (select item_id from products where user_id=u.user_id) as ITEM_IDS
from users u
```

Comment: what is the version of `SQL Server` you are using ? do a `PRINT @@version` to check

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4057116) - 11.0.7462.6 (X64) 
 Jan  5 2018 22:11:56 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Web Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: Thanks for you help. You pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked.

```
select u.fname,
       u.lname,
  STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + CAST(item_id AS VARCHAR(20)) AS [text()]
     FROM products AS P
     where P.user_id=u.user_id
     FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, NULL) AS ITEM_IDS
from users u
```